# Do you know any good miniature wargame that is fairly easy to learn and play?

Tags: recommendations

I have various miniatures (sci-fi and fantasy one), some grounds (tree, hills, barricades) and many many dices. I host regularly every week in a Barcelona bar a boardgame meeting with new people to boardgames and from various language and nationality. I have many new enthusiasts, but few experts in gaming.

I am looking something to propose for the occasional gamer, and at the same time, a miniature wargame that is fairly easy to learn and have fun to play.

**What is a bad suggestion:** Dungeon & Dragons, any of Warhammer series, historical reconstruction of fights

**What is a good suggestion:** A own made auto generated labyrinth game (I have plenty of tiles), a game with a 15 minutes creating character and quick battles, a game that can play several people at the same time.

Can you please help me with some suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

We used to play Necromunda years ago--I'm not sure if it's still around. Like Warhammer it is/was a Games Workshop game, but I think it could suit your purposes. It came with enough "terrain" in the box to support a game. It would be well suited to a multi-player game (think of an urban gang-fight free-for-all). Only a few miniatures were needed so that barrier is low and a quick gang could be set up quickly by new players while the seasoned set up the terrain.

Comment: A good suggestion, although best for 2 players.  The box is long out of production, but a revised all-in-one rulebook is still readily available.

Comment: I played once Necromunda, but it doesn't look as "fast game". I mean you have to build your gang, equip them... it doesn't look quick to prepare for people that don't know wargaming. thx for the suggestion

Comment: @Littlemad: Unfortunately Necromunda is almost certainly not going to come in under 15 minutes for setup with even one first-time player.

Answer (score 2):

### [Savage Worlds](http://rpggeek.com/rpg/286/savage-worlds)

Savage Worlds is an RPG system - but contains a strong game of miniatures combat! The rules are "Fast! Furious! and Fun!" as advertised.

- You can learn the game from the book in an evening and teach it in minutes.
- You can use all your minis, tiles, and terrain.
- You can choose an existing setting or create one yourself.
- Unlike many wargames, it's designed to handle many participants in a battle.
- The rulebook is small and inexpensive.
- There is an active and welcoming Savage Worlds community online.

I think it makes a good fit for your criteria and hope you give it a try.

Comment: Looks promising, I am gonna have a look and report to you :D

Comment: @Littlemad - I hope it works out well for you! I can't wait to hear how it goes!

Answer (score 2):

Heroscape is a solid game that may you may be able to repurpose.  It uses hexes that you could either incorporate in or toss and use whatever you have.  Most importantly it has a "simple rules" variation built in to the rulebook that allows for pretty easy pick-up-and-play.

Comment: I saw many times ago this game, but I do not want to buy stuff like basic hexes, when I have plenty of tiles and other things that can be used as such. Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Mordheim lends itself to a small model count pretty well, and the rules are available on Games Workshop's website for free.

Answer (score 1):

[Fuzzy Heros](http://www.fuzzyheroes.com) seems like a nice simple set of rules, though you'll probably want to adjust the theme a bit.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.manticgames.com/Shop-Home/Dwarf-Kings-Hold.html

It's a very, very fast game with quick rules.

Answer (score 0):

[Quikwars, which is a simplified version of Brikwars](http://www.brikwars.com/rules/2005/quikwars.htm), looks pretty easy.